# Свой элемент управления Windows Forms наследующий Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, элементы-управления, visual-basic

Нужно при инициализации объекта создавать для него **`Graphics`**, как это сделать, куда впихнуть `_gr = MyBase.CreateGraphics` или это делается как-то иначе?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
public class MyPanel : Panel
{
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        //base.OnPaint(e);
        var g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Red), 0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если в **`Update()`** засунуть?

Comment: Этот метод не виртуальный и переопределить его не выйдет. Судя по комментарию, этот метод предназначен для принудительной перерисовки контрола, то есть, как я понимаю не совсем то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Ну, я **`Update`** для примера привёл, в общем, то, что хотел, сделал, спасибо.